# Does downvoting affect the reach of a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

Does downvoting affect the reach of a question?

I mean people will not open those question that have more negative votes.
And what about question visibility?

Comment: What does "reach of question" mean exactly? Do you mean the visibility of the question?

Comment: Yes, what you described is pretty much the whole point of downvotes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Questions with low [scores](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (= sum of up and downvotes) are hidden on the front page. The thresholds are

- -4 on parent sites
- -8 on meta sites

Source: [Answer by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769).

For example, if a question receives 3 downvotes and 0 upvotes, it's still shown on the SO front page (tab "Interesting" activated). If it then gets another downvote pushing its score to -4, it's no longer shown.

Further reading: [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) ("The goal is no longer to show you a simple flat list of the last (n) active questions — that’s not even possible any more based on sheer question volume — but, instead, to narrow the list to a *subset of active questions that we think you will be interested in.*")

Answer (score 7):

Yes, downvotes affect the visibility (or "reach") of a question.

This is in fact very much the point of downvotes. As stated in the help center page on [Why voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) :

> Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how …
>
> > ... good content rises to the top
> >
> > ... **incorrect content falls to the bottom**

and

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while **voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.**

Downvotes are the primary way in which one communicates to other users that they should not spend time opening and looking at a post.